# Multiple jQuery scroll event performance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know which is the best method to create different events during the scroll.
Are there any differences (maybe even in performance) between these two codes?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
// Do things A
}
$(window).scroll(function() {
// Do things B
}
```

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
thingsA();
thingsB();
}
function thingsA() {
// Do things A
}
function thingsB() {
// Do things B
}
```

Is there any specific advice to follow to improve the performance and loading of the page in these cases?

Comment: Any difference between the two approaches will be negligible, but the latter is structured better. Any performance issues with scroll events happen because the event handler is called per pixel scrolled. As such I'd suggest you look to debounce the event handlers if you run in to problems. If you could give an example of the logic performed in the `thingsX()` functions we will be able to provide a canonical answer to the issue.